# AbsoluteSizeSpan working slow in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app consisting of EditText in which the user can change the text size as well as color of text dynamically on entering text in EditText. I am able to change the color of current text in between previously entered text using span in customized InputFilter, but on changing text size in span inside a InputFilter, lag comes when entering text in between perviously entered text.

Here is my code for InputFilter:

```
class MyTextFilter implements InputFilter{
@Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try{
            Spannable span = new SpannableString(source.subSequence(start, start + 1));
            if(colorSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("red")){
                span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, start + 1,     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else if(colorSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("green")){
                span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, start + 1,     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else if(colorSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")){
                span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, start + 1,     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("small")){
                span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 10, null, null), start, start + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")){
                span.setSpan (new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 20, null, null), start, start + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("large")){
                span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 30, null, null), start, start + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }

//   if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("small")){
//   span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(20), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//   }
//   else if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")){
//   span.setSpan (new AbsoluteSizeSpan(60), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//   }
//   else if(sizeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("large")){
//   span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(80), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//   }

            Log.e("span", "="+span);
            return span;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably hava too many spans, use this to dump them http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#dumpSpans(java.lang.CharSequence, android.util.Printer, java.lang.String)

Comment: Tried it, not working. It only prints spans in a CharacterSequence.

Comment: what "not working" ? how many spans did it dump?

Comment: It didn't dumped spans at all.

Comment: How did you call TextUtils.dumpSpans() ?

Comment: `Printer printer = new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, "TAG");`
`TextUtils.dumpSpans(span,printer,"spans: ");`

Comment: the first param should be EditText.getText()

Comment: It is printing log and still hanging.

Comment: so use Spanned.getSpans

Comment: Yes I tried using this in filter to clear spans.

Comment: Only SizeSpans (RelativeSizeSpan, AbsoluteSizeSpan and TextAppearanceSpan) are working slow, all other color spans are working fast. So I don't think that there is problem with calculating span. @pskink

Comment: so try to find a bottleneck http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: to be honest why do you set 1 char long spans each time user is typing something?

Comment: I want to make user to change color and size of text in runtime. Like when user selects green color and large text size the text entered should be of green color and large size, and in between if user changes color to red and size to small, the text entered should be small red. And the previous green large text should remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

your approach is wrong, try to add the following in onCreate:

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setTextSize(30);
SpannableStringBuilder b = new SpannableStringBuilder("smallbsmall");
Object what = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40);
b.setSpan(what, 5, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
et.setText(b);
et.setSelection(6);
setContentView(et);
```

now the "cursor" is between big "b" and small "small" text, now type "i" and "g". you see what happens? now you have big "big", and you did nothing in your code - that's the way the spans work

Comment: Here is an attached screenshot link of what I want to do with edittext

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=218430011676301&set=a.218430028342966.1073741833.100005279112524&type=1&theater

Can change text color as well as size of text dynamically, there are three buttons for color and size selection. @pskink

Comment: @Shankar yes i know what you mean

Comment: So by using your code in onCreate editText size is applied to that smallbsmall string only, not what the user will enter. So you have any idea about why there is a lag in EditText when the cursor is placed in between and span is set in between previously entered spans? @pskink

Comment: @Shankar your problem is that you set a span for **every** character you type in your EditText, that means you have dozens of spans instead of just few

Comment: Yes I know that, for text color only, there is no problem or lag in handling large number of spans in EditText filter. But it lags only when size span is set in between already written text.